# HTML/CSS/PHP contact form is sending blank fields

Tags: php, html, css, forms, contacts

I'm by no means a web designer/coder, but I have enough general knowledge to get my website going. Just a simple portfolio website.

I'm having some problems with my contact form though. It's strictly CSS, HTML and PHP but when I put in the information (name, email and message) to test it, it sends me an email with those field headings, but no content. For example, the email displays as;

Name:
Email:
Message:

Even when filled out with information.

I have a feeling it's something small and a stupid error, so any help is greatly appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<div id="contact-area">
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Name"/>
<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email"/>
</form>
</div>
<div id="contact-area2">
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>
</form>
<div id="submit-button">
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit-button" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "contact@brettlair.ca";
$EmailTo = "contact@brettlair.ca";
$Subject = "Contact Form";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.htm\">";
exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.html\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have your form fields in one form, and the submit button in another. They need to be in the *same* form.

```
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Name"/>
<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email"/>

</div>
<div id="contact-area2">

<textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>

<div id="submit-button">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit-button" />
</form>
```

Comment: See the submit button example here: 

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: Damn, I had a feeling it would be something like that. I was having a hell of a time separating the form horizontally like that without creating two areas.

Comment: @JohnConde Is there any chance you can take a look at my CSS if I post it? I'm not sure how else I can have the 'Name' and 'Email' blocks one size and the 'Message' block another size to get the look I want without splitting them up into two divs.

Comment: @JohnConde Disregard my last request, I misread what you posted. Thanks for your help, it works flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

```
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name']));
```

There is no `Trim` function, should be `trim` (lowercase).